# Inverse Laplace Transform of the following complicated form

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

What would be the inverse laplace transform of the following:

I mean I want to solve this:

$$
\large \mathcal {L^{-1} [ \mathcal {L}[{sin(at+b)}] . \mathcal{L} [{e^{xt}}] . e^{cs}}] =  ?
$$

Comment: Do you know that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F(s) G(s)) = f(t) \ast g(t)$?

Comment: You need to read about convolution.

Comment: @user61527 yes I know this property but how can I apply it here ?

Comment: By writing down a convolution of a couple of functions, and calculating it.

Comment: @user61527 I read about convolution but it seems it works for two functions. What would become of $\ e^{cs}$ in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brut force calculus : First, we introduce the Laplace transforms of the given functions. Second, we separate the fractions. Third, we apply the inverse Laplace transform.

[image]